# hang in printf on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, printf

So here is my minimal sample:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  printf("First stuff\n");
}
```

My program hangs on the printf. I've dug into the disassembly through the debugger. Execution enters printf, makes its way into `call qword ptr [__imp___stdio_common_vfprintf (07FF67A6D73F0h)]`

From here, the jumps/calls are unnamed. The code is hung on a `call` to an explicit address. Is this anything that someone's seen before? I'm using MSVC tools v142, VS 2019, SDK 10.0.18362.0

My program was running fine, and suddenly started hanging on printfs. I thought I'd introduced some sort of memory corruption, until I moved the printf to the first line of my program and saw the same result. Deleting my output folder and recompiling has no effect. Though it does seem like *some* code changes can get me out of this odd mode, it will start happening again randomly.

Also, closing Visual Studio and reopening, then rebuilding, seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you try std::printf(...)?

Comment: No, I'm not using std. I think it's a bug in Visual Studio. Closing and reopening VS, then recompiling resolved the issue

Comment: Maybe try to reproduce this in your own environment, by opening a clean cmd and testing this after compilation.

Comment: _"Is this anything that someone's seen before?"_ Seen in VS 2015. But it's fixed (I think) in the newer versions.

Comment: "So here is my minimal sample" Did the problem happen with minimal sample? If it did, then problem with compiler (or compiler/linker setting). If it didn't, then it's not the problem with `printf` function, but other part of your code

Comment: yes it did, on my machine. i think it was a bug in MSVC. I had a workaround, but it would be interesting to know what caused it